# How can I perform actions on Sheet A by checking cell value if exists, and use it as a key to skip in the next execution as it was already processed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Forgive the basic question, but after 15 attempts at different variations, I come here with this.. Full code below, but the following statement

```
    if (data[i][11] <> "YES")
```

does not seem to be executing properly in any of the various methods I've tried, I am sure I am doing something wrong somewhere else in this script but for the life of me cannot see it. Hoping a new set of eyes can help..

I am trying to collect data on Sheet A, process it and place it on Sheet B, and update a key in Sheet A.  If the script is run again, it should not pick up Sheet A's already processed items (via the Key - currently in the 12th column and indicated as "YES"). In each instance the script continued to process all rows regardless of if it - leading me to think it isn't actually the conditions I am providing..

Hope this is clear. Appreciate any push in the right direction.

Another of the attempts:

```
var jiraupdated = data[i][11]; 
if (jiraupdated !== UPDATED)
//and various similar replacing with different types, methods, etc.
```

Full script:

```
var UPDATED = "YES";

function formatJIRASheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = lastRow-1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastRow); //rowCount for data
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('JIRA Sheet');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    // Fetch values on initial data
    var row = data[i];
    var date = row[1]; // 2nd col
    var customername = row[2]; //3rd col
    var test = row[3]; 
    var testt = row[4];
    var summary = row[5];
    var actualoutcome = row[6];
    var exptoutcome = row[7];
    var customeremail = row[8];    
    // Form new description (merge of other fields) 
    var description = (date + " " + dftdescription + " " + test + " " + testt + " " + actualoutcome + " " + exptoutcome); // target col 2
                        
    
    // This is the failing check, continuing to write records to next sheet even though they've already been covered in previous runs.  I've tried maybe 15 different methods to fix this and have came up short.  
    if (data[i][11] <> "YES") { 
      sh1.appendRow([null, "Bug", null, summary, description, customeremail, customername, null, null, null, null, null, "Low", "Low", null, null, null, null, null]); 
      sheet.activate();
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(UPDATED);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function formatJIRASheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const v=rg.getValues();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  v.forEach(function(row,i){
    var date=row[1];
    var customername=row[2];
    var test=row[3]; 
    var testt=row[4];
    var summary=row[5];
    var actualoutcome=row[6];
    var exptoutcome=row[7];
    var customeremail=row[8];    
    var description=(date + " " + "undefined" + " " + test + " " + testt + " " + actualoutcome + " " + exptoutcome);
    if(row[11]!="YES") { 
      sh1.appendRow(['',"Bug",'',summary,description,customeremail,customername,'','','','','',"Low","Low",'','','','','']); 
      sh.getRange(sr + i, 12).setValue("YES");
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: You're a saint - worked perfectly.. very simple as well. Thank you.